# Can't restart nginx https certificate routine private key missmatch

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

**I have updated my certificate on Gandi like this :**

```
sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out mywebsite.com_encrypted.key 4096

sudo openssl req -new -key mywebsite.com_encrypted.key -out mywebsite.com.csr

cd /etc/nginx/ssl/
sudo nano mywebsite.com.crt # > pasted the Gandi certificate in this file

sudo wget https://www.gandi.net/static/CAs/GandiStandardSSLCA.pem

sudo cat GandiStandardSSLCA.pem >> mywebsite.com.crt

sudo openssl rsa -in mywebsite.com_encrypted.key -out mywebsite.com.key

sudo chown root:root mywebsite.com.key
sudo chmod 400 mywebsite.com.key
```

Everything was working good with older certificate but since I updated configuration with new certificate here is is my log on nginx. I can't restart :

**Nginx logs :**

```
2015/05/12 20:53:03 [emerg] 7515#0: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

What's wrong with process ?

Configuration of nginx is ok.

**Here is my nginx configuration :**

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. It looks like you replaced the key in */etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.key*, leaving the original certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.crt unchanged (the *mywebsite.com.crt* certificate is still bound to the original key - and you cannot change that - **public key is an integral part of X509 certificate**). This is exactly what openssl is trying to tell you - you are trying to use a certificate with different private key that was originaly created with.

BTW: I also have no idea why you created a certificate request (along with the new key) and then left it unused (without actually using it to create new certificate).